# Android - print from app on mobile printer

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, printing, bluetooth

I have an app which prints some text using a [Rongta RRP-200](http://www.rongtatech.com/products-look-58.html) mobile printer, connected with my phone via blueetoth.

For this, I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer

I'm able to connect my device to the printer and even run the print function from my app, which gives me back a message informing me that data was sent. However, the printer does nothing (with the exception of its lights turning on).

This is the function (from the plugin) that attempts to print my text:

```
boolean printText(CallbackContext callbackContext, String msg) throws IOException {
    try {
        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

        // tell the user data were sent
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data Sent");
        callbackContext.success("Data Sent");
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errMsg = e.getMessage();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, errMsg);
        e.printStackTrace();
        callbackContext.error(errMsg);
    }
    return false;
}
```

What could possibly go wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

Found that the plugin worked correctly, but you have to give a complete line to the printer to make it print something. Therefore, add `\n` at the end of your string. This is the function to print something, in case anyone needs it (its in a Ionic app controller):

```
$scope.print = function(text) {
    BTPrinter.connect(function(data){
        BTPrinter.printText(function(data){
            BTPrinter.disconnect(function(){},function(err){
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(err)
            }, "Your Printer device")
        }, function(err){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(err)
        }, text + "\n")
    }, function(err){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(err)
    }, "Your Printer device");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i have the same printer and wrote a little plugin its work awsome for me. I tested in RPP200 and RPP300.

https://github.com/CXRom/cordova-plugin-rpp

```
Rpp.Connect("00:0E:0E:0B:7B:93", // <-- MAC Address of the printer
  function(print) {
    //At this point we send the action but we need to wait until the connection
    console.log(`connect ok ${JSON.stringify(print)}`);
  },
  function (err){
    console.log(`connect err ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
  });

//Ask is device is connected
Rpp.IsConnected(function(conn) {
  //Send to print
  Rpp.Print({
    marginTop: 10, //Margin before print
    marginBottom: 10, //Margin after print
    lineSpacing: 50, //Size of line
    lines: [ //Lines to print
      { text: "Title", align: 1, bold: true, underline: true, size: 17 }, //long name properties
      { text: "Subtitle", a: 1, b: true, u: true, s: 17 }, //short name properties
      { text: "normal line" },
      { text: ":)", h: true }
    ]
  }, function(res) {
    console.log(`print ok ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
  }, function(err){
    console.log(`print err ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
  });
}, function(err) {

});
```

Comment: Does it Work with Providing the name of Printer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still necessary but try [Cordova-Bluetooth-Printer-Plugin by TruewindIT](https://github.com/TruewindIT/Cordova-Bluetooth-Printer-Plugin).

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "Cordova-Bluetooth-Printer-Plugin",
    "cordova_name": "Cordova Bluetooth Printer Plugin",
    "license": "MIT License",
    "author": "Truewind IT",
    "platforms": [ "android"],
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/TruewindIT/Cordova-Bluetooth-Printer-Plugin.git"
    }
}
```

`$("#console")` is just a textarea tag for printing status in my android app

`$("#deviceList")` is a ul tag that will contain the list of the connected devices

Listing connected devices:

```
BTPrinter.list(function(success){
        $("#console").append("Success");
        $("#console").append("::"+JSON.stringify(success, null, 2)+"::");
        success.forEach((e) => {
                $("#deviceList").append(`<li value="${e}">${e}</li>`)
            });
      },function(err){
        $("#console").append("Error\n");
        $("#console").append(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
      })
```

Connect and Print

NOTE: **`BTPrinter.print()`** is the correct method not `BTPrinter.printText()` based on the `BluetoothPrinter.java`

```
$('#deviceList').on('click', 'li', function () {
      var deviceId = $(this).val();
      var deviceName = $(this).text();

      BTPrinter.connect(function(data){
        $("#console").append("Connect Success\n");
        $("#console").append(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)+"\n")
        
          BTPrinter.print(function(data){
            $("#console").append("Printing Success:\n");
            $("#console").append(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)+"\n");

              BTPrinter.disconnect(function(){
                
               $("#console").append("Disconnect Success:\n");
              },function(err){
                $("#console").append("Disconnect Error");
            }, deviceName)

          },function(err){
              $("#console").append("Failed in Printing:\n")
              $("#console").append(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)+"\n")
          }, "Hello world text.\n\n\n\n")

      },function(err){
        $("#console").append("Connect Error\n");
        $("#console").append(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)+"\n")
      }, deviceName)
      // Attempt to connect to the selected device
  });
```

`cordova-bluetooth-printer-plugin/src/android/BluetoothPrinter.java` line 121

```
else if( action.equals("print") ) 
        {
            try 
            {
                String msg = args.getString(0);
                print(callbackContext, msg);
            } 
            catch( IOException e ) 
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return true;
        }
```